# Authorize facebook app to post on page without user auth

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there no way to link/authorize a facebook app to a facebook page, without having to rely on user auth and their tokens ?

In my example i have a website with articles, and i want the option to publish those to a facebook page. But all examples i find require the user publishing the article to authenticate, and if he has admin access to the facebook page, i can then use that authentication to impersonate the page and post on its behalf.

Many problems arise due to this, some of the users might not have admin access to the facebook page, thus making the articles they publish on the website being posted by them (and not the page itself) on the facebook page. Also id like to not have the "connect with facebook" step every time someone publishes and article on the website.

Comment: Its unclear what are you trying to say!

Comment: Let me see if I understand this clearly: you have users that are logged in through Facebook and you want them to be able to post articles on your site as well as the ability to post those articles to **your** Facebook page?

Comment: no, not mine. to a facebook page belonging to the same organisation that owns the website.. They want the articles they publish through the website cms to be posted on their facebook page's wall. So that users following their page will get the updates in their feeds..

Comment: And also, the users are not logged in through facebook, they are logged in through the cms which has its own user database that has nothing to do with facebook.

Comment: You'll have to authenticate user to facebook, list all pages he have admin rights to, check if user has appropriate permissions to publish to page, then you store the page id & token in your database, when publishing you can use the stored data without re-authenticating the user again.